# GitHub + Eclipse Workflows

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am sure this is a RTFM thing, but after a few days of research I still cannot determine the correct (or *best*) workflow for this.

- I have an Eclipse Workspace with a number of Java Projects in it and a number of C++/Arduino projects.
- I want to start using GitHub as an online repository (easily reachable from outside my private LAN dev environment) for my projects
- I was thinking I would like a separate C++/Arduino and Java GitHub repos.  More could come for Python, PowerShell, etc. (But I will happily entertain other recommendations for repo structures).

Outside of the actual mechanics of using Egit, I cannot figure out the most appropriate workflow/folder structure for accomplishing this.  Should I create local Git repos and push to GitHub as a remote?  Should I use GitHub's web interface to import the entire Eclipse Workspace? Should I work directly with the Eclipse Workspace or have separate Git folders?

I guess the crux of my problem is that after reading a few related posts on this site I get conflicting advice about creating a local repo from the Eclipse workspace vs. a separate local repo.  I think I need to understand this distinction first before I ultimately determine the best overall workflow.

I apologize for the broad nature of this question, but I hope that the community can help me narrow the workflow process design (or the question itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things up front:

1. **Never** put your entire workspace in source control; projects: yes, workspace: no. The `.metadata` folder contains data specific to that location and your machine, and that's ignoring any potential security risks with making it public.
2. eGit works with your git clones' own metadata, so if you're more comfortable doing certain things from the command line, go for it.  I know I am, but I still appreciate the UI and decorations that eGit provides.  Just make sure any automatic refresh/update preferences on the **Workspace** or **Git** preference pages are turned on.
3. You probably want the repository to contain multiple projects, rather than having a separate repository for each one. That way histories and changes that belong together *are* together. Nest the layout however you like, but remember that you're not constrained to a single repository for everything, either.

I don't know that there's a *best* practice for this, especially with projects that already exist, but projects should themselves be relocatable.  My recommendation, after backing it all up:

1. Make the Github projects, clone their repos locally. I do it this way, from the command line, to save me any headaches with the history, remotes, and refs. I don't think you can modify the repository metadata in this method, though.
2. Move the workspace projects into the local clone. You can delete them from the workspace (be sure **not** to delete the underlying files), physically move the directories while outside of Eclipse, and then [import them as projects](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Importing_projects) back in from the **Git Repositories** View--unless they're Maven projects, in which case it's better to use M2E's import wizard.
3. Stage, commit, and push the projects up to the remote origin. For Java projects, don't forget to set the `JRE System Library` in the **Java Build Path** to use an *Execution Environment*. It's a simple bit of indirection that makes them more portable across machines.

Comment: I appreciate very much your detailed answer. It was helpful and well-written. I wonder if it was intentional that you started with "Two things up front" and then listed 3 things.  If so, I wish I had bonus points to give you.

Comment: Ha, no, I think I added the third one because I remembered other questions about that and didn't realize it "broke" the structure.